# Keystore file not set for signing config release flutter issue

Tags: flutter, apk

When I want to build `apk` for my app, I am facing this issue

`Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'. > Keystore file not set for signing config release`

I've seen all links but couldn't solve my issue

```
 signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Take hint from image and change your code as done in line 63.[image]

Comment: this is already included